# Pull out all the Genres movie wise

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to exract "genres" from below code, movie wise that is, the first movie has 3 genre(Action,Adventure,Animation), so i want that it should show all these 3 together and similarly for rest movies.
I am able to extract the genres using beautiful soup but individually. Need your help guys to know how to extract it movie wise(all genre for 1 movie, then all for next, and same pattern for the rest).

```
<h2><span class="rank">1. </span>
<span class="title_span">Steven Universe The Movie</span>  (2019) </h2>
<p><span class="genres" onclick="change_genre(28);">Action</span>, <span class="genres" 
onclick="change_genre(12);">Adventure</span>, <span class="genres" 
onclick="change_genre(16);">Animation</span>, </p>
<p><i class="rating_grade8 fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="rating"> 
<strong>9.0</strong></span> / 2,954 votes</p>

<h2><span class="rank">2. </span>
<span class="title_span">Forrest Gump</span>  (1994) </h2><p>
<span class="genres" onclick="change_genre(35);">Comedy</span>, <span class="genres" 
onclick="change_genre(18);">Drama</span>, <span class="genres" 
onclick="change_genre(10749);">Romance</span>, </p>
<p><i class="rating_grade8 fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="rating"> 
<strong>8.8</strong></span> / 180,853 votes</p>
```

My code for extracting genres individually below:

```
genres=soup.find_all('p')for genre in genres:
gene=genre.find_all('span', attrs={'class':"genres",'onclick':True})
for gen in gene:
    print(gen.text)
```

I am writing the results in a SQL DataBase thats why i need all the genres together :)
Expected result:

1. Steven Universe The Movie (2019) Action,Adventure,Animation

I hope i was clear in making my query.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the fact, that `<h2>` tag with title comes first, then `<span class="genres">` next.

First we get the movie name, put it to dictionary as key, with value as list. Then populate this list with genres.

For example:

```
txt = '''<h2><span class="rank">1. </span>
<span class="title_span">Steven Universe The Movie</span>  (2019) </h2>
<p><span class="genres" onclick="change_genre(28);">Action</span>, <span class="genres"
onclick="change_genre(12);">Adventure</span>, <span class="genres"
onclick="change_genre(16);">Animation</span>, </p>
<p><i class="rating_grade8 fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="rating">
<strong>9.0</strong></span> / 2,954 votes</p>

<h2><span class="rank">2. </span>
<span class="title_span">Forrest Gump</span>  (1994) </h2><p>
<span class="genres" onclick="change_genre(35);">Comedy</span>, <span class="genres"
onclick="change_genre(18);">Drama</span>, <span class="genres"
onclick="change_genre(10749);">Romance</span>, </p>
<p><i class="rating_grade8 fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="rating">
<strong>8.8</strong></span> / 180,853 votes</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

all_movies, current_movie = {}, ''
for tag in soup.select('h2, span.genres'):
    if tag.name == 'h2':
        current_movie = tag.get_text(strip=True)
        all_movies[current_movie] = []
    else:
        all_movies[current_movie].append(tag.get_text(strip=True))

# print data:
for movie, genres in all_movies.items():
    print('{} {}'.format(movie, ', '.join(genres)))
```

Prints:

```
1.Steven Universe The Movie(2019) Action, Adventure, Animation
2.Forrest Gump(1994) Comedy, Drama, Romance
```

Comment: Thanks much for your explanation!
I tired the same code but its giving me below result(All genres at last title):

    1.Steven Universe The Movie(2019)'
    '2.Forrest Gump(1994) Action, Adventure, Animation Comedy, Drama, Romance

Comment: Seems it is selecting all the 'h2' tags and then coming to genres,hence it adds all the genres to the last title.

Comment: @Hemantjoshi What version of `bs4` are you using? I'm on `beautifulsoup4==4.9.1`. Running the code I posted prints desired result.

Comment: seems i am using '4.8.2' 
Can i update it using pip:
''' pip install beautifulsoup4 '''

Comment: it dint work with 'pip install...' , but found a way to do it online.
Now its working... Thanks buddy! :)